# Purrr map over multiple models to store results in dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have got the following example:

```
mtcars %>%
    group_split(cyl) %>%
    map(~lm(mpg ~ wt, data = .x)) %>%
    map_dbl(~.x$coefficients[[2]])

[1] -5.647025 -2.780106 -2.192438
```

I also want to store the intercept, so I thought this might work:

```
mtcars %>%
    group_split(cyl) %>%
    map(~lm(mpg ~ wt, data = .x)) %>%
    map_df(~.x$coefficients)

Error: Argument 1 must have names
```

However I get this error. What am I doing wrong and how can I store both coefficients in a dataframe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The coefficients return a numeric vector, we can change it to dataframe and then use `map_df`.

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>%
  group_split(cyl) %>%
  map(~lm(mpg ~ wt, data = .x)) %>%
  map_df(~.x$coefficients %>% t %>% as.data.frame)

#  (Intercept)      wt
#1      39.571 -5.6470
#2      28.409 -2.7801
#3      23.868 -2.1924
```

Comment: brilliant, thank you, didn´t know I can use the pipe operator inside map :)